# how to spawn or call a process from multiple processes in erlang

Tags: erlang

I want to spawn a process from multiple functions and create a link to the process. how to convert received signals in to message in a system process. I want to make "paralleljoin" system process and after it receives a ('EXIT', pid, normal) message from its linked processes(taskTwo, taskThree, TaskFour) it will spawn another process(taskFive) but this not properly working in my code i.e "taskFive" is not executing.

```
    -module(model).
    -compile(export_all).
    start() ->
        io:format("codes of start event \n"),
        %The spawn method calls the taskOne function with no parameters
        spawn(model, taskOne, []),
        Pid1 = spawn(model, paralleljoin, []),
        register(join2,Pid1 ).
    taskOne() ->
        io:format(" code for business logic  of task one \n"),
        spawn(model, parallelsplit, []).
    parallelsplit()->
        Pid2 =  spawn(model, taskTwo, []),
        register(task2, Pid2),
        Pid3 =  spawn(model, taskThree, []),
        register(task3, Pid3),
        Pid4 = spawn(model, taskFour, []),
        register(task4, Pid4).
    taskTwo() ->
        io:format("code for business logic  of task two \n"),
        link(whereis(join2)),
        exit(whereis(join2), normal).
    taskThree() ->
        io:format(" code for business logic  of task three \n"),
        link(whereis(join2)),
        exit(whereis(join2), normal).
    taskFour() ->
        io:format(" code for business logic of task four \n"),
        link(whereis(join2)),
        exit(whereis(join2), normal).
    paralleljoin()->
        process_flag(trap_exit, true),
        Task2 = whereis(task2),
        Task3 = whereis(task3),
        Task4 = whereis(task4),
        case get(messagesreceived) of
            undefined -> put(messagesreceived, {nil, nil, nil});
            {Task2, Task3, Task4} ->
                spawn(model, taskFive, [])end,
        receive
            {'EXIT', Task2, normal} ->
                put(messagesreceived, setelement(1, get(messagesreceived), Task2));
            {'EXIT', Task3, normal}->
                put(messagesreceived, setelement(2, get(messagesreceived), Task3));
            {'EXIT', Task4, normal}->
                put(messagesreceived, setelement(3, get(messagesreceived), Task4));
            Other ->
                ignore %Do something, or do nothing
         end,
    paralleljoin().
taskFive()->
    io:format("code for business logic of task five \n").
```

Answer (score 0):

> what is wrong with my code

1. There is no function named `model:paralleljoin()`.

> when I spawn it from each function it creates 3 different process

2. Every time you call `spawn()`, erlang creates a new process.  It's as simple as that.  spawn() does not check the name of the variable on the left hand side of an assignment to decide what to do.

If you want the taskTwo(), taskThree(), and taskFour() processes to all link to a common process, then you need to pass the common process as an argument to each of those functions, like this:

```
parallelsplit()->   
    Pid = spawn(model, paralleljoin, []),
    spawn(?MODULE, taskTwo, [Pid]),
    spawn(?MODULE, taskThree, [Pid]),
    spawn(?MODULE, taskFour, [Pid]).

taskTwo(ParallelJoin) ->
    io:format("code for business logic  of task two \n"),
    link(ParallelJoin).

...
...
```

Another option is to *register* the common process, which creates something like a global variable that can be accessed from any process:

```
start() ->
   io:format("codes of start event \n"),
   register(somename, spawn(model, paralleljoin, []) )
   spawn(model, taskOne, []).
...

taskTwo() ->
    io:format("code for business logic  of task two \n"),
    link(whereis(somename) ).  %% whereis() returns the pid of a registered name
```

Comment: ok, thanks a lot now I understand how to create a link to a common process.But I want to ask about a system process, When a system process receives an error signal, the signal is converted into a message of the form {'EXIT', Pid, Why}. If the process terminates without an error, then "Why" will be the atom "normal" in my case I want to make the make the common process "paralleljoin" a system process and added the builtin function process_flag(trap_exit, true) to change into system process ,but this not working for me. to look at the code I have added the full source code.

Comment: @Kiros, I responded in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't expect anyone to look at your code if it isn't indented properly.   What is your indenting strategy?  Is each line indented a random number of spaces?  Are you not able to look at the code after you post it and discern that the indenting is a mess?  If you cannot figure out on your own how to post code on a computer programming forum, then you need to do some research with google.  Is it possible that you are not using a computer programming editor?

2)  If you look at the definition of `erlang:process_flag/2`, it says:

> When trap_exit is set to true, exit signals arriving to a process are
>   converted to `{'EXIT', From, Reason}` messages, which can be received as
>   ordinary messages. If trap_exit is set to false, the process exits if
>   it receives an exit signal other than normal and the exit signal is
>   propagated to its linked processes. Application processes are normally
>   not to trap exits.
>
> Returns the old value of the flag.
>
> See also exit/2.

That tells you that if a process is trapping exits, the process will receive messages of the form  `{'EXIT', From, Reason}`.  However, nowhere does it define what type `From` is nor what type `Reason` is.  Is `From` an atom? The docs do say, "See also exit/2", and if you check the docs for `erlang:exit/2`, it says:

> If Pid is trapping exits, the exit signal is transformed into a
>   message `{'EXIT', From, Reason}` and delivered to the message queue of
>   Pid. `From` ***is the process identifier*** of the process that sent the exit
>   signal.

That tells you that From needs to be a Pid (but it appears that you already knew that because in your comment you said that exit signals will be converted to messages of the form `{'EXIT', Pid, Why}`).

Now lets look at your pattern for matching exit messages:

```
{'EXIT', task2, normal} ->
```

The 'EXIT' atom will match position 1 in an exit message, but for `From` you specify the atom `task2`.  Is an atom a Pid? Hint: read the lone comment in the code example I posted before.

Note that you can send messages using a registered name, i.e. an atom, because `!`, which is shorthand for erlang:send/2, is defined in the docs like this:

> **erlang:send(Dest, Msg) -> Msg**
>
> Dest can be a remote or local ***process identifier*** [i.e. a Pid], a
>   (local) port, ***a locally registered name*** [i.e. an atom], or a tuple {RegName,
>   Node} for a registered name at another node.

But, it is not generally the case that a registered name can be used instead of a Pid.

3) Instead of this:

```
receive
    MESSAGE->   
        case MESSAGE of
            {'EXIT', task2, normal} ->
                put(messagesreceived, setelement(1, get(messagesreceived), taskTwo));
            {'EXIT', task3, normal}->
                 put(messagesreceived, setelement(2, get(messagesreceived), taskThree));
            {'EXIT', task4, normal}->
                put(messagesreceived, setelement(3, get(messagesreceived), taskFour))
        end
end
```

you can write:

```
receive
    {'EXIT', task2, normal} ->
        put(messagesreceived, setelement(1, get(messagesreceived), taskTwo));
    {'EXIT', task3, normal}->
         put(messagesreceived, setelement(2, get(messagesreceived), taskThree));
    {'EXIT', task4, normal}->
        put(messagesreceived, setelement(3, get(messagesreceived), taskFour))
end
```

The difference is: with your code, a run time error will occur if a message other than the ones you specified arrives--because that's what happens when a case statement does't handle all the possibilities--while in my example the receive will block if a message other than the ones specified arrives.  You can always prevent a receive from blocking by adding a catch all:

```
receive
    {'EXIT', task2, normal} ->
        put(messagesreceived, setelement(1, get(messagesreceived), taskTwo));
    {'EXIT', task3, normal}->
         put(messagesreceived, setelement(2, get(messagesreceived), taskThree));
    {'EXIT', task4, normal}->
        put(messagesreceived, setelement(3, get(messagesreceived), taskFour));
    Other ->
        %Do something, or do nothing
end,
%%No matter what message was sent to this process, 
%%execution will continue here.
```

Comment: sorry for the indenting strategy and thank for your suggestion,  actually I am using eclipse. task2, task3, and task4 are registered names of a process  under parallelsplit() but they are not registered I do no what is the problem and how to do it in order to compare with the {'EXIT', pid, why}? I tried to pass the pid of terminated process like {'EXIT', whereis(task2), normal} but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use OTP, supervisor.

Have one process spawn and restart the worker, and pass the pid to other processes that need it or use a named process and that way you don't need to pass the pid.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to pass the pid of terminated process like {'EXIT', whereis(task2), normal} but not working.

Did you get an `illegal pattern` error?  If so, you need to write:

```
Task2 = whereis(task2),
receive
    {'EXIT', Task2, Why} ->
```

A pattern cannot contain an expression:

> **Pattern Matching**
>
> Pattern = Expression
>
> The Pattern consists of data structures that can contain both bound
>   and unbound variables, as well as literal values (such as atoms,
>   integers, or strings).
>   ...
>   ...
>   The Expression consists of data structures, bound variables, mathematical operations, and function calls. It may not contain unbound values.
>
> Erlang Programming (Cesarini, Thompson)

Comment: it says Error in process <0.101.0> with exit value:
{{case_clause,{nil,nil,nil}}, that  is  the code                                           case get(messagesreceived) of
            undefined -> put(messagesreceived, {nil, nil, nil});
            {Task2, Task3, Task4} ->
                spawn(model, taskFive, [])end,  is always nill it does not spawn taskFIve

Comment: A case_clause error means that your case doesn't handle all possibilities.  To see what message is actually causing the error, add a catch all case: `Any -> io:format("X=", [Any])`.  It's not clear to me why a message from a crashed process would match `undefined` or `{Task2, Task3, Task4}`.

Comment: ok, thank you. If I have not missed the concept my idea is the processes paralleljoin() has to wait for all messages to arrive from processes (taskTwo(), taskThree() and taskFour) and after it receives all messages it has to trigger process taskfive(). is it link(pid) and exit/2 enough to trapp the message {'EXIT', From, normal} message in the paralleljoin()?